# In python using pandas, I want my program to search strings in column A and column B in csv file and write results in column C

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```py
import pandas as pd
path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\"

filename = 'file.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path+filename)
arr = []
for i in range(len(df['Column_A'])):


    if df['Column_A'][i] == pd.np.nan:
        continue

    if df['Column_A'][i] is not pd.np.nan:
        if 'ABC' in df['Column_A'][i]:
            arr.append('X')
        elif 'DEF' in df['Column_A'][i]:
            arr.append('Y')
        elif 'GHI' in df['Column_A'][i]:
            arr.append('Z')

        else:
            arr.append('')
    else:
        arr.append(' ')
        continue

df['Column_C'] = arr

filename = 'output.csv'

df.to_csv(path+filename)
```

In the above code I want to add column_B to search strings ("ABC", "DEF","GHI") along with column_A to write results in column_C as desired if match is found.

Comment: And what is your question? have you an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me in your question if:

- you want to add 'X' if **both** Column_A and Column_B include 'ABC', or
- add 'X' if Column_A includes 'ABC' and 'Y' if Column_B includes 'DEF'.

In the first situation Column_C will be 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '', or ' '. But what would happen if Column_A has 'ABC' **and** Column_B has 'DEF'?

```
import pandas as pd

path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\"

filename = 'file.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path+filename)
arr = []

lookup = {'ABC': 'X', 'DEF': 'Y', 'GHI': 'Z'}

for col_A, col_B in zip(df['Column_A'], df['Column_B']):
    to_append = ''
    if col_A is not pd.np.nan and col_B is not pd.np.nan:
        for key in lookup.keys():
            if key in col_A and key in col_B:
                to_append = to_append + lookup[key]
    arr.append(to_append)
df['Column_C'] = arr

filename = 'output.csv'

df.to_csv(path+filename, index=False)
```

In the second situation Column_C will be 'XX', 'XY', ..., 'YZ','ZZ', '', ' '.

```
import pandas as pd
path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\"

filename = 'file.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path+filename)
arr = []

lookup = {'ABC': 'X', 'DEF': 'Y', 'GHI': 'Z'}

for col_A, col_B in zip(df['Column_A'], df['Column_B']):
    to_append = ''
    if col_A is not pd.np.nan and col_B is not pd.np.nan:
        for key in lookup.keys():
            if key in col_A:
                to_append = to_append + lookup[key]
            elif key in col_B:
                to_append = to_append + lookup[key]
    arr.append(to_append)

df['Column_C'] = arr

filename = 'output.csv'

df.to_csv(path+filename, index=False)
```

In both situations I also added index=False when writing the csv file , because I assumed you wanted to have a file exactly as your input file, but with an extra column, Column C.

Comment: Thanks.. second scenario worked for my requirement but to avoid printing same string twice I changed "if key in col_B:" to "elif key in col_B:".. Now the output in Cloumn_C is 'X','XY','Z',' '.

Comment: Do you want to check Column_A or Column_B even if the other one is nan?
If you think this answer is the solution to your problem, please indicate it as the accepted answer.